# Create a function to display HTML/data based on site admins role?

Tags: shortcode, user-roles

I need to make a shortcode to display some HTML on a page based on site admins "role"? Not the logged in user but the site admin's role. By default the role is 'administrator' and the only other role is 'pro_user'. So if they are a "pro_user" I want to echo the the first "HTML type 1" and if not to output "HTML type 2" as you can see below:

I tried this but did something wrong & get blank output on the page.

```
add_shortcode( 'add_my_form', 'get_form_on_role' );
function get_form_on_role() {
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $user = new WP_User( get_current_user_id() );
        $roles = $user->roles;
        if( $roles[0] == 'pro_user' ) {
            echo 'HTML type 1';
        }elseif( $roles[0] == 'administrator' ) {
            echo 'HTML type 2';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to instanciate a new WP_User with the current user id when a user is not logged in ... replace ! is_user_logged_in() by is_user_logged_in(). Also, enable WP_DEBUG in your wp-config.php to display php errors

Comment: Do not shout please!

Comment: In addition to @AntoineGuillien a shortcode should not echo anything, all output should be returned

Answer (score 1):

I think below line of code is unnecessary, which is wrong if you looking for logged in user result.

```
if( ! is_user_logged_in() )
```

Please use below code, I make some changes for solution.

```
//Add a hook for a shortcode 'add_my_form' tag...
add_shortcode( 'add_my_form', 'get_form_on_role' );

//Create sortcode API used function...
function get_form_on_role() {
    if(is_user_logged_in() ) {//If user is logged in...

        //Get current user role information...
        $user = new WP_User( get_current_user_id() );
        $roles = $user->roles;

        $returnTxt = '';//Initialize return text variable...

        if( $roles[0] == 'pro_user' ) {//If user having 'pro_user' role...
            $returnTxt = 'HTML type 1';
        }elseif( $roles[0] == 'administrator' ) {//If user having 'administrator' role...
            $returnTxt =  'HTML type 2';
        }
        return $returnTxt;
    }
}


/*
    This will display 'HTML type 1' is user logged in with 'pro_user' role, 
    If logged in user with 'administrator' then it will print 'HTML type 2'...
*/
//You can use sortcode by API like... 
<?php echo do_shortcode("[add_my_form]");?>
```

Reference: [Shortcode_API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

Let me know if there is any doubt/query regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! This does work if the user is logged in however this is for a public page in a multisite setting so if possible I would like it to display to all users and base the output on the site admin/owners role.

Sorry if I was using the wrong code that checked if logged in and that misled you as to what I needed.

What I would like is 'HTML type 1' above to return if the sites admin for that pages role is 'pro_user'. It does that now but only if that admin is logged in.

Then if not 'pro_user' or if role='admin' to display 'HTML type 2'.

Is that possible to get the site admins role and not the logged in users role?
The page authors role also would not work in this case.

thank you for your help!!